# Neo4j Passing a variable through WITH in Cypher even with no MATCH

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In Cypher, if I connect multiple queries together with `WITH`:

1) I am passing a variable from one `MATCH` to another with `WITH`

2) I am planning to print this variable at the end

If the last `MATCH` does not output any results, then my interested variable is also lost and I can not print it.

Is there anyway to pass a variable or a list from one query to another and even if the last `MATCH` does not output any results, I can still return it?

Comment: replace last MATCH with OPTIONAL MATCH

Comment: The problem with OPTIONAL MATCH is that it causes all the rest of variables in the pattern to be none null, and that is not what I want. I want the similar behavior of MATCH, but for a specific variable only I want its content to pass through several MATCHs.

Comment: @Afshin I think you need to show an example of your query. And an example of input data. And the desired result. And show that it does not work.

Comment: In fact, what I am trying to achieve is that I have many function calls represented as a graph, and I am trying to list the functions which do not have a speficic path in them. To do that, I pass the original functions list with WITH between MATCHs, and I also do some manipulation on the original function list to find the list of functions to exclude. The problem is that when there is nothing to exclude, the list of my original functions is not passed either due to the issue I described above.

Comment: As `@GovindSingh` said - `OPTIONAL MATCH`.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to see if I can make it work with OPTIONAL MATCH.